# Is this any different from "What job should I take?"

Tags: discussion

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17338/7777

I don't understand how this question at it's core is any different from a "What job should I take?" question, which as I understand it is verboten here.

Paraphrasing here:

*The new job (which I already accepted) is nice, pays more, and moves my career along.

The old job could be nicer, might be negotiated into paying as much, and might promise to move my career along.

Should I give them a discount and thus be able to choose the old company?*

Comment: No its not . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't apparently -- it has been closed and deleted by the community.

The system works!

Comment: There's a system? ;-)

Comment: @Joe, the system may contain a lot of uncertainty, but it's still a system. A work in progress is still a work, and all that jazz.

Comment: there's jazz? I'll take five.  ;-)